# How to disable the fadingedge in the support listfragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm using an android.support.v4.app.ListFragment to display a list inside a Viewpager.

On devices with Android 2.3 and lower the ListFragment displays fadingedges. The whole App is kept in the Holo design and so the edges are looking a little bit out of place.

How do I disable those fadingedges in a ListFragmen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More correctly, do this in the ListFragment's onActivityCreated method

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setFadingEdgeLength(0);
}
```

If you do it in onResume(), you will potentially make redundant calls to setFadingEdgeLength() during the fragment's lifecycle.

More info see Google's [Fragment Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not disable the fading edge in XML I have a workaround:

```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      ListView listView = getListView();
      if (listView != null) {
         listView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
      }
   }
```

I do this in the onResume to have a higher chance that the view is already available.